# Downcasting non-polymorphic types?

Tags: c++, c++20

Please consider the following C++20 program:

```
struct B { B(); private: int whatever; }; // non-aggregate
struct D : B { D(); int x; private: int whatever2; }; // non-aggregate

int main() {
   D* d = new D;
   d->x = 42;
   B* b = (B*) d;
   D* d2 = (D*) b;
   return d2->x;
}
```

Is this program ill-formed or have undefined behaviour?

That is, is it allowed to cast a pointer to the base subobject of a derived object of non-polymorphic type to a pointer to the derived object itself?

If so, would one of the `*_cast<T>` functions be more appropriate than the C-style cast?

(Also, if the pointer is to a `B` object that isn't a base subobject of an object of type `D`, then its undefined behaviour, right?  The implementation has no way to check if the cast is correct, as it does with a `dynamic_cast` ?)

Comment: Assigning the D* to the B* is fine---you don't even need the cast: `B* b = d` would work.  Casting back from a B to a D, you *do* need a cast.  As for which cast form, if you *know* that your B is really a D, `D* d2 = static_cast <D*> (b)` would be the preferred C++ way.  If you're not certain, `D* d2 = dynamic_cast <D*> (b)` will do the cast as expected if `b` is a `D*`, or if not, it yields a null pointer.  Note, `dynamic_cast` incurs some runtime cost.

Comment: @Perette you cannot do `dynamic_cast` on non virtual types. But you're right for the rest, `static_cast` is the preferred way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this program ill-formed or have undefined behaviour?

This program is well formed. You can cast a pointer from a base type to a subtype without any issues.

> If so, would one of the *_cast functions be more appropriate than the C-style cast?

Certainly! The default cast to use is `static_cast<T>(...)`. It will avoid casting from/to unrelated types that would incur undefined behaviour.

For example, C-style casts will accept your code [even if `B` and `D` are unrelated](https://godbolt.org/z/55T147), but [refuses the code using static_cast](https://godbolt.org/z/ahxh5a)

Comment: C style falls back on reinterpret. Note there is one case where C style does something dynamic and static will not, isn't UB, and isn't reinterpret.